# Firebase Authentication failed after publishing the app in Apple playstore

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I have published an App both on Google and Apple Playstore. The app on Google is working fine. The app on Apple is giving error while authencating the user - [firebase_auth/invalid-app-credential] invalid token. Although it works absolutely fine while on development mode - wonder what seems to be the problem.